# convert CSS Hover to JS onClick for Dropdown Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a simple dropdown menu when a user clicks on an image. Currently I'm using CSS hover but it doesn't stay so I want to convert it to a JS onClick function.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}
ul li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
display: block;  
}
ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
</style></head><body>
<ul>
<li>
<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thincons/100/menu-128.png" width="20px;" height="18px;"/>
<ul class="lang">
<li>Web Design</li>
<li>Web Development</li>
<li>Illustrations</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little jQuery, we can easily `toggle` a class on or off to represent 'showing' the menu:

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("activated");
});
```

And changing the CSS (instead of `:hover`) to:

```
ul li.activated ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

The HTML only needs that first `li` element to have an id, which lets us use jQuery to bind a click event to it.

```
<ul>
<li id="menu">
```

You can see it all in action on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r12c01sj/).

**Edit:** For a non-jQuery solution, you can use the following Javascript code:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('menu');
myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('activated');
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks brotha, you da best. :)